# Convert Text to image using php

Tags: php

I am able to create image but not able to write anything on image.

I am not getting any error message as well. Here is my code:

```
$ouput ="uploads/jersey/img1.jpg";
$x=720;
$y=480;
$image = imagecreate($x,$y);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image,95,73,255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);
$fs =40;
$rotation = 0;
$origin_x = 20;
$origin_y = 20;
$font = "./arial.ttf";
imagefttext("$image",16,0,0,16,$black,$font,"test");
imagejpeg($image,$ouput);
```

Can you help me to solve the issue ?

Comment: If you ask something make sure you use some phrase which are easily understandable to everyone. Don't keep it as short as you did.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
imagefttext("$image",16,0,0,16,$black,$font,"test");
```

To this:

```
imagefttext($image,16,0,0,16,$black,$font,"test");
```

---

Here is the error message:

```
PHP Warning:  imagefttext() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /tmp/index.php on line 15
```

Are you looking in the correct place for your script's error messages?  Either run your script from the command line or look at your webserver's error log. It will be somewhere like like `/var/log/httpd/error_log`